# block direct access on port 8080

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I have an app running on a service, behind a nginx server, using unicorn.

If I access http://server.com I get the app, up and running...But I still can access app on port 8080, like http://server.com:8080 but this time, without assets (which are beign served by nginx)

How do I block direct access to port 8080 on my prod. server?

The server is an Ubuntu 12.04

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com; 
  root /home/deploy/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: Try using a firewall, which blocks incoming traffic on that port. As easy as that. As long as a service keeps listening on that port, that service will respond when called.

Comment: Make unicorn and nginx use a domain socket.

Comment: @Catnapper like `upstream github {
    server unix:/data/github/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}` ?

Comment: @LuizE. Yes, and configure unicorn for that socket as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make unicorn and nginx use a domain socket.  For nginx:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/path/to/socket fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Then pass '-l /path/to/socket' to unicorn, or alter your unicorn config file:

```
listen '/path/to/socket'
```